# WPF ToolTip animation and template

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, tooltip

I am trying to set up a `ToolTip` similar than Microsoft uses in Outlook 2013:
[image: Animated ToolTip]

How can I incorporate the following behaviour:

1. `ToolTip` stays open as long as the mouse cursor is inside it
   *(my version: `ToolTip` closes automatically after certain time has elapsed)*
2. Allow clicking components inside `ToolTip` (for example "See more online" above is clickable)
   *(my version: `ToolTip` is already closed when trying to move mouse cursor inside it)*
3. `ToolTip` "scrolls" from top to down when it opens
   *(my version: `ToolTip` opens without animation)*

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="ToolTip example" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="12000">
      <TextBlock.ToolTip>
           <ToolTip Padding="5">
                <Grid>                                      
                </Grid>
           </ToolTip>
     </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: To clickable tooltip use popup.

Comment: I fake it with EventTriggers and ControlTemplates, can show you how I do it in Silverlight if you'd like, wouldn't be too different for WPF but it works great and does all of the above without an actual "popup"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late now, however, I have something like this.  A WPF button has a `ToolTip` (not a `Popup`) than has a non-standard `InitialShowDelay` and Animation.

The styling for this is done in the `Button`, and **not** the `ToolTip`.  My example:

```
<Button.Style>
  <Style x:Key={x:Type Button} TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="{StaticResource ToolTip.Delay.Open}" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="{StaticResource ToolTip.Delay.Duration}" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Bottom" />
    <Style.Resources>
      <PopupAnimation x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.ToolTipPopupAnimationKey}">Slide</PopupAnimation>
    </Style.Resources>
  </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

You can, of course, add this to your general Button styling or just a one-off.

This works well with “Slide” and “Scroll” but not “Fade” as the latter requires `AllowsTransparency = True` and I didn't have time to investigate that.

I hope this helps someone!